# Trying to line up glyphicon with <a> element

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

I want my glyphicon to line up next to my  tag. But it looks like its being placed below it.
How do I place the glyphicon so that it appears next to my  element?
Here is my html and an image of what it looks like

```html
<div class="col-md-3 submenucol1 text-right">
  <ul id="managelinks" class="nav nav-stacked">
    <li id="overviewlink"><a href="#overviewlink">Overview</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="false"></span>
    </li>
    <li id="detailslink"><a href="#detailslink">Details</a>
    </li>
    <li id="calendarlink"><a href="#calendarlink">Calendar</a>
    </li>
    <li id="imageslink"><a href="#imageslink">Images</a>
    </li>
    <li id="listinglink"><a href="#listinglink">Listing</a>
    </li>
    <li id="addresslink"><a href="#addresslink">Address</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your CSS also?

Comment: I don't really have any css related to this part of my code. just the HTML you see above. The classes and id's are all bootstrap code

Comment: I took it myself using a screen capture tool in Windows. why?

Comment: What styles are applied to .submenucol1, #managelinks and .nav .nav-stacked - they all would affect your layout - can you maybe setup a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the glyphicon span inside the a tag?

```
<li id="overviewlink"><a href="#overviewlink">Overview <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="false"></span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `col-md-4` for div , if it doesn't help increase width of **li**  manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the anchor links `display:inline-block`.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6byma1tw/)

```css
#managelinks a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-3 submenucol1 text-right">
  <ul id="managelinks" class="nav nav-stacked">
    <li id="overviewlink"><a href="#overviewlink">Overview</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="false"></span>
    </li>
    <li id="detailslink"><a href="#detailslink">Details</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="false"></span>
    </li>
    <li id="calendarlink"><a href="#calendarlink">Calendar</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="false"></span>
    </li>
    <li id="imageslink"><a href="#imageslink">Images</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="false"></span>
    </li>
    <li id="listinglink"><a href="#listinglink">Listing</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="false"></span>
    </li>
    <li id="addresslink"><a href="#addresslink">Address</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="false"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue as well. I use `<i>` tags instead which tend to work well. `Span` can add `padding` sometimes

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="false"></i>
```